# saved instance bundle is null in onCreateView for DialogFragment

Tags: android, fragment, bundle

I am saving a key value pair before displaying the warning dialog. However the `onCreateDialog()` for the dialog is called with a null bundle. Is there something extra I need to do to pass the bundle to the dialog?

```
MyDialogFragment testFrag= new MyDialogFragment();
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putString("car-type", "Audi");
testFrag.setArguments(args);
testFrag.show(getFragmentManager(), "info");
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can retrieve the arguments via `DialogFragment.getArguments()`.

The `savedInstanceState` is only used when a configuration change occurred. It is being filled in `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)` and later passed to the new `DialogFragment` in `onCreate()` and `onCreateView()`. The first time a Fragment or Activity gets created it is `null`.

Answer (score 3):

The `setArguments` bundle is retrieved using `getArguments`.

The `savedInstanceState` bundle that is a parameter of the `onCreateDialog` method is the bundle populated in `onSaveInstanceState`.

These 2 are completely unrelated.